# How can I execute *.class file in any folder?

Tags: javac

this is my project tree:

```
.
├── README.md
├── package.json
└── src
    └── xyz
        └── pagenote
            ├── HandlerTestA.class
            ├── HandlerTestB.class
            ├── Main.class
```

If I am in the folder `src`, I can execute Main.class by

```
src# java xyz.pagenote.Main
```

It works, but I want to execute it in the current folder, I have tried

```
.# java ./src/xyz/pagenote/Main
```

It doesn't work, what can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the command `java`, the default classpath is the current working directory `(.)`.

So when executing `xyz.pagenote.Main` from the `src` directory, and the `classpath` flag is not specified, `java` will look for the class file in `src/xyz/pagenote.class`

So to execute from a directory other than `src`, you have to specify the classpath like:

```
$ java -classpath /path/to/src xyz.pagenote.Main
```

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution, we can point a classpath for java:

```
.# java -classpath ./src xyz.pagenote.Main
```

this command will let java execute it right